# Invoice header and invoice line fact table extraction question

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, sql-data-warehouse

I have a question regarding the best practice regarding the loading of invoice header and  line data inside InvoiceLineFact table. I am following the Kimball recommendation where I bring all the dimensionality of the header down to the line items like shown on the picture :

[image: HeaderLineFact table example]

For data extraction part we use store procedures created on our DWH SQL Server which are automatically executed via job in sequential order. What we do in every procedure is that we target the transaction tables on remote/linked server (DynamicsNAV db sql server):

Example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM LinkedServer.NAVDB.dbo.InvoiceHeader
INNER JOIN LinkedServer.NAVDB.dbo.InvoiceLine
```

The problem is that the our ETL is started to slow down from day to day.

I wanted to ask if this is the efficient thing to do or there is a better way of doing this, like extracting the raw data in separate table and then join it on the DWH server, or maybe placing it inside SSIS package as it is.

Comment: I forgot to write down the join clause but I think that you should get the point of my question. It is joined by InvoiceID attribute.

Comment: 1) From Source To Staging Table Then 2) From Staging To DWH! Divide the package and rule it better!

Answer (score 0):

> if this is the efficient thing to do

No.  Joining distributed tables and sending complex queries to operational systems are both problematic.

> or there is a better way of doing this,

Yes

> like extracting the raw data in separate table and then join it on the DWH server

Yes.  This is standard best-practice for building data warehouses.